# gperftools inexactitudes with CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY

Tags: c++, c, gcc, profiling, gperftools

I have a task for which `gprof` seems that cannot be used. Callgrind is helping a lot here, but when found a solution more `gprof`-like, i. e., gperftools, dove into them to try.

So I wrote a dummy program and did several trials like these:

```
0:10:1386682334:user@host:~$ time gcc test.c -o test -lprofiler -Lgperftools-2.
1/.libs/ -g

real    0m0.085s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.032s
0:11:1386682357:user@host:~$ time CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=50 CPUPROFILE=~
/test_profile LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/gperftools-2.1/.libs/ ./test && ~/gperftools-2.
1/src/pprof test test_profile --text

PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 14/0/216

real    0m7.157s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.672s
Using local file test.
Using local file test_profile.
Removing killpg from all stack traces.
Removing do_system from all stack traces.
Total: 14 samples
      14 100.0% 100.0%       14 100.0% do_system
       0   0.0% 100.0%       14 100.0% __libc_start_main
       0   0.0% 100.0%       14 100.0% _start
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2  14.3% bar
       0   0.0% 100.0%       14 100.0% foo
       0   0.0% 100.0%       14 100.0% main
0:12:1386682465:user@host:~$ time CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=50000 CPUPROFIL
E=~/test_profile LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/gperftools-2.1/.libs/ ./test && ~/gperftools
-2.1/src/pprof test test_profile --text

PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 80/0/520

real    0m7.199s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.704s
Using local file test.
Using local file test_profile.
Removing killpg from all stack traces.
Total: 80 samples
      78  97.5%  97.5%       79  98.8% do_system
       1   1.2%  98.8%        1   1.2% __find_specmb
       1   1.2% 100.0%        1   1.2% __libc_waitpid
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   1.2% _IO_vfprintf_internal
       0   0.0% 100.0%       80 100.0% __libc_start_main
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   1.2% __printf
       0   0.0% 100.0%       80 100.0% _start
       0   0.0% 100.0%       27  33.8% bar
       0   0.0% 100.0%       79  98.8% foo
       0   0.0% 100.0%       80 100.0% main
```

CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY is documented [here](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) to be defaulted at 100 and being *How many interrupts/second the cpu-profiler samples*. Am estranged at setting it to 50 on a 7 seconds dummy program is sampling only 14 times, and at setting it to 50000 is sampling only 80 times.

I would want to know whether when needed more precision can be get with this simple environment change, and whether is CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY broken in gperftools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program only had between 0.008s and 0.048s user execution time.  The profiler only profiles time spent in user space executing, and so I think your results are expected.

Try running a dummy program that spends 7 seconds doing actual computation.  For example, compute Ackermann's function.

Comment: I did it and it seems that that host with that configuration of the git head is able to sample up to 250 times per second, which saves me for the time being.